# How to select multiple elements using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="c3">
      <input>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

    <input>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to match the `input` and `textarea` elements from the `div.c3` with only one CSS rule. I'm using

```
div.c1 .c2 .c3 input,textarea { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

but this matches all textareas, not only the one cotnained in the `c3` div.

Is this possible, or must I write separate CSS selectors for each element?

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/Bp3qn/1/ for the live example.

---

I updated http://jsfiddle.net/Bp3qn/3/

I only need the input and textarea contained in the c1->c2->c3 containers to be highlighted, not other combinations.

Comment: Today, [`div.c1 .c2 .c3 :is(input, textarea)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:is) is possible to avoid repetition.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that is very cool. I didn't know about :is()

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need the other elements in the selector, unless you ***only*** want to match `.c3` if it is within `div.c1 .c2`:

```
.c3 input,
.c3 textarea {
    /* that's it! */
}
```

If you do (per your edit), use this:

```
div.c1 .c2 .c3 input,
div.c1 .c2 .c3 textarea{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/Bp3qn/6/

---

> after edit: thats what i'm trying to avoid (my real stylesheet is a lot more complex and css rules are longer, and its getting hard to read)

In that case, to make things easier just add another class to that `.c3` like this:

```
<div class="c3 special">

.c3.special input,
.c3.special textarea{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/Bp3qn/7/

If you MUST have the selector as small as possible and there are no other children of `.c3.special`, just use the star selector (almost never recommended):

```
.c3.special * {border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

Comment: after edit: thats what i'm trying to avoid (my real stylesheet is a lot more complex and css rules are longer, and its getting hard to read)

Comment: i cant add another class (i'm trying to keep the markup simple also:) ) and i cant select all children, but it seems that this is as good as it gets. thx

Comment: @Quamis: Yep that's as good as it gets. Just use comments and good code style to keep your CSS readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.c1 .c2 .c3 input,.c3 textarea { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

Comment: this matches every `textarea` whose parent’s class is `.c3`, so it does not solve the question

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic but I wanted to add some points on this because I just ended up here while trying to apply the same king of logic.
And thanks to this question, I know now that we should reconsider that logic a bit.

First, the upvoted answer does solve the question but I don't understand why the use of `.c1 .c2` classes in the CSS.

As @Wesley Murch first wrote, that should be enough:

> .c3 input,.c3 textarea {
> /* that's it! */ }

It's also ok to specify a bit more with:

```
div.c3 input,
div.c3 textarea {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

which is already the shorthand for:

```
div.c3 > input,
div.c3 > textarea {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

But, IMO, unless you really have no control of what's inside your `div`, you should simplify everything by just adding one more class in your HTML and then you'll also end up with only one rule which will be even a bit easier to read:

HTML update with one more class `special-border-color` for exemple:

```
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="c3">
            <input class="special-border-color">
            <textarea class="special-border-color"></textarea>
        </div>
            
        <input>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS simple rule:

```
.special-border-color {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: `.c1 .c2 .c3` were there because the the input & textarea should be styled with `style1` only in that context. If the parents was simply .c3, then the styling should be `style2`. So yes, there was a need for that.

Comment: also, please note that `div.c3 input` and `div.c3 >input` are not shorthand of eachother. One applies to ALL inputs, no matter how deep, the other one applies to input on the FIRST CHILD LEVEL.

Comment: and yes, If you have access to the way the html is generated then of course it's easier to add a custom class like `special-border-color` and use that for styling. In my case, I didn't want to change the way the html was generated (it was a small widget-like call that was used thousands of times, but only in one case it needed a different styling)